# How can i add a space between a Label and a combo box in Ruby code

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am very new to Ruby, i need to add a space between a Label and Combo box in ruby file.

Sample code:

```
def render_search_combo_box(project, selected_value=nil)
  return unless User.current.logged?
  s = "<select id='search_options' name='search_options'>"
end
```

i have tried adding 'nbsp;' before 'select' but no result came.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think, it`ll be better to solve your problem using CSS.

For example (in css file):

```
#search_options {margin-left: '10px'}
```

However, why you not just use rails form helpers to build your form?
You can achieve same result like this (in view):

```
<% if User.current.logged? %>
  <%= select_tag "search_options" %>
<% end %>
```